# Connect to a local db when invoking serverless function

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, serverless, serverless-framework

I'm writing a new serverless function and I'd like to test out the database on my local laptop before deploying to AWS. When executing the Lambda locally via `sls invoke local --function <function name>` it does not seem to find the Postgres database. I've tried using `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`.

The error's tend to look like:

```
failed to connect to `host=127.0.0.1... dial error (dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused)
```

Connections to this database via `psql` succeed.

I don't know much about serverless's internals. When run locally is it using docker containers? Would that account for it not seeing regular localhost?

Comment: Hey there, what runtime are you using? For serveral of them, the function will be launched inside a Docker container, which might not be able to actually access stuff running on your host machine.

Comment: @pgrzesik I'm running serverless v3 on a Mac. The serverless code itself is written in golang

Comment: I'm unfortunately not experienced with Go functions, but I'm pretty sure they would be launched within a Docker container, which won't have access to localhost. Would you be able to post the full output of the `invoke local` command?